# How to group rows together in new table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I'm trying to group multiple rows together to form a new table. I'm doing this to find the count of each type of invoice delivery method for each customer.

I've tried this code

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT customer_id,
(COUNT(invoice_send_method WHERE invoice_send_method='Fax' GRPUP BY(purchase_date || '_' || item_id))),
(COUNT(invoice_send_method WHERE invoice_send_method='Mail' GRPUP BY(purchase_date || '_' || item_id))),
(COUNT(invoice_send_method WHERE invoice_send_method='Email' GRPUP BY(purchase_date || '_' || item_id)))
FROM my_table;
```

But it returns a syntax error after the first instance of invoice_send_method (before the WHERE).

In order to count as one instance of an invoice shipping method, I created a rule that it had to be a unique combination of purchase_date and item_id.

[image: Current Table]

[image: Desired Table]

Is there a better way to do this? It seems like I can't introduce WHERE or GROUP BY statements within the COUNT but I don't know how else to do it while still checking through all invoice delivery methods.

I am using MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is syntactically wrong.
Use this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT 
  t.customer_id,
  SUM(t.invoice_send_method = 'Fax') fax_count,
  SUM(t.invoice_send_method = 'Mail') mail_count,
  SUM(t.invoice_send_method = 'Email') email_count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM my_table) AS t
GROUP BY t.customer_id;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hHAEydEh8eAqg3E9LdfHdY/0).
Results:

```
| customer_id | fax_count | email_count | mail_count |
| ----------- | --------- | ----------- | ---------- |
| 10863865    | 0         | 1           | 0          |
| 12010467    | 1         | 0           | 0          |
| 2771929     | 0         | 0           | 3          |
| 5317588     | 0         | 0           | 1          |
| 7484618     | 0         | 3           | 0          |
| 7924567     | 1         | 0           | 0          |
| 9320463     | 1         | 0           | 0          |
```

Comment: Why sum instead of count? Also, would using sum allow me to insert a WHERE clause and GROUP BY clause into it?

Comment: Mysql evaluates `invoice_send_method='Fax'` as 0 or 1. So it is summing 1s. In your expected results I don't see `purchase_date`. Do you need grouping by `purchase_date` also?

Comment: This gives me an error of "function sum(boolean) does not exist"

Comment: I ended up trying with SUM(CASE WHEN t.invoice_send_method = 'Fax' THEN 1 END) and that did not produce errors

Comment: Are you sure that you are using MySql?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use ORDER BY instead of GROUP BY:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT customer_id, purchase_date, item_id,
COUNT(invoice_send_method WHERE invoice_send_method='Fax') as count_fax, 
COUNT(invoice_send_method WHERE invoice_send_method='Mail') as count_mail,
COUNT(invoice_send_method WHERE invoice_send_method='Email') as count_email,
FROM my_table
ORDER BY purchase_date, item_id;
```

You can remove the purchase_date and item_id from the SELECT if you dont want to see them, it's just easier to test it out that way.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this would solve only half of it. I am looking to merge rows with identical combinations of purchase_date and item_id. Customer 7484618 ordered item 360 three times on 10/17/19 but should only be counted as having received one email for that

Comment: try 'GROUP BY customer_id' before the ORDER BY line, that should solve the issue.